# JQuery make xml string from DOM model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a DOM with different nested divs and inputs (with values):

```
    <div id ="div_id1">
<div id ="div_id2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>input 1:</td>
            <td><input id="i1" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>input 2:</td>
            <td><input id="i2" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>input 3:</td>
            <td><input id="i3" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id ="div_id3">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>input 4:</td>
                <td><input id="i4" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>input 5:</td>
                <td><input id="i5" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to make XML string recursively according to this structure?
Like this:

```
<div_id1>
<div_id2>
    <i1>value 1</i1>
    <i2>value 2</i2>
    <i3>value 3</i3>
    <div_id3>
        <i4>value 4</i4>
        <i5>value 5</i5>
    </div_id3>
</div_id2>
```

UPD:

I tried function like this:

```
function makeXml(nodes) {
var $result = $('<' + nodes.attr('id') + '>');
$.each(nodes, function(i, node) {
    var nodeId = node.getAttribute('id');
    var $el = $('<' + nodeId + '>').text($('#' + nodeId).val());
    alert(nodeId + $('#' + nodeId).val());
    $el.appendTo($result);
    var $children = $(node).children();
    if ($children.length > 0) {
        makeXml($children).appendTo($el);
    }
});
return $result;
```

};

But it does not work properly (does not correctly handle nested divs).

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: "Does anyone have any solution?" Have you tried something?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so that we can help you to fix it? Http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: your HTML is invalid. I suggest you fix that before going any further.

Comment: `<tr></tr>` should also be in a `<table></table>`

Comment: You can't just make up html tags, they may not be created/nested the way you intend them to be in all browsers. Instead, create an xml string then parse it as xml. (that means do not pass it to `$()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the options (create a XML-string):

```
var str = '';
function makeXml(obj) {
    var children = obj.children();
    if (children.size() != 0) {
        $.each(children, function(i, v) {
            var $val = $(v), id = $val.attr('id');
            if (typeof($val.attr('id')) !== "undefined") {
                str += '<' + id + '>' + $('#' + id).val();
                makeXml($val);
                str += '</' + id + '>';
            } else {
                makeXml($val);
            }
        });
    }
}
```